# Is there a CSS way to position an HTML element vertically following the golden ratio?

Tags: html, css, web

I want to position an HTML element in the horizontal middle and vertical golden ratio with CSS only. The height of the element must be absolutly flexible, so I can not just set the `top-attribute` and the `element-height` to a percentage value. Is there any way to do that?

Schematic representation:

[image: diagram]

In the image, arrows of the same color are in golden ratio to each other (38.2% : 61.8%). The dotted line is only imaginary.

Comment: Aren't the red arrows the only ones relevant in this situation?

Comment: You can position your content at for example 38.2% form the top with `margin-top: 38.2%;`. I don't think it's possible to react to the elements height and decrease the margin to position it in this way above the dotted line. -- There is nothing like `38.2% - (this.height*0.382)` in CSS. -- Maybe **LessCSS** can do more here with it's variables, but then again you could use JS, which is of course no CSS-only solution. - For the horiontal positioning you can simply use `text-align: center;` on the body and set it back to left for the content. May require `display: inline-block;` for the content.

Comment: Scott and I seem to have gotten different interpretations of the question.  Is your intent to have that gray box be some html element whose height is determined by its content?  That was my interpretation.

Comment: @James: I see your point. My interpretation was based on that note in the corner that said "browser-viewport." Of course, for my "reproduction" I took the liberty to size the `body` tag down in `width` to give it a ratio relation. I assume that he just wanted a "visual center" on the page to be at the golden ratio (the horizontal line).

Comment: @James: I can't speak for user1030151's intent, but upon further reflection, your interpretation really would not make sense. The golden ratio is a visual thing, and in this case 1) visually: if you can't see the proportion all at once (you have to scroll the body) then there is no visual point to it; 2) practically: if the gray rectangle was first determined by content height, then likely when someone first comes to the site, they would be looking at no content, for the top red arrow space would probably fill the height of the window with any significant amount of content.

Comment: Sorry for my tardy answer. @Scott: Thank you for your very awesome demonstration. But unfortunately it's not what I meant. I'm sorry@James: You have understand my

Comment: ..
@James: You have understand my question correct. Your idea is very interesting. But I hoped that there is a more beautiful way.

Thank you for all - Sorry for my very short and clumsy answer (and question) .. this are my very first steps in english newsgroups.

Comment: Well, I'm glad James interpreted you correctly. However, I must say that I still hold by points 1 and 2 in my previous comment--the visual aspect of the golden ration would be lost if one had to scroll off screen, and the practical implication (if the gray area is intended to be content; you may intend it to be something else) could be quite horrible on usability. However, I still enjoyed forming my solution even if I did misinterpret your intention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found an answer, after eight years :D

Because of new CSS technologies :)

see my CodePen:
https://codepen.io/eHtmlu/pen/ExjZrQb

or the same live example here on stackoverflow:

```css
/***********************************/
/* Here is where the magic happens */
.container {
  display: flex; /* we need the flex technique */
  flex-direction: column; /* and we need it vertically */
  align-items: center; /* horizontally we just center the box */
}

.container::before {
  content: " ";
  flex-grow: .38196601; /* This is the magic number that places the box vertically in the golden ratio */
}
/* That's it!! */
/* except you want to place it relatively to the viewport - see below, where we position the container element */
/***********************************/


/* To place the container at the golden ratio of the viewport, we need to set the height of "html" and "body" to 100% and margin to 0. Then we use the same technique as we used for the box. */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

body::before {
  content: " ";
  flex-grow: .38196601;
}


/* The rest are just a few environmental and styling settings */

.container {
  border: #000 solid 1px;
  height: 20em;
  width: 30em;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.box {
  width: 10em;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: .5em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1em rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">This box is located vertically in the golden ratio of the container element.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe the math works out to be this (vertical centering only discussed here):

[**See Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/shuxn/) (thanks to Daniel for making that)

CSS

```
div {
    position: absolute; /* or fixed */
    top: 23.6%; /* height is 100% of viewport * 38.2% (blue)  * 61.8% (red) */
    bottom: 38.2%; /* height is 100% of viewport * 61.8% (blue) * 61.8% (red) */
}
```

That should get your ratio correct for green. Height is flexible to viewport size.

EDIT: **More explanation.** Note that the blue arrows start out dividing 100% of the height into 38.2 and 61.8. The red top arrow is going to be 61.8 of the top  blue section (38.2), hence 23.6. The red bottom arrow is going to be 61.8 of the bottom blue section (61.8), hence 38.2. Now the double check: 23.6 + 38.2 = 61.8 (that is the TOTAL distance of the two red arrows added together). So their ratio is 23.6/61.8 = 38.2% and 38.2/61.8 = 61.8% (red arrows meet your golden ratio). The green is 100 - 61.8 (the red arrow totals) = 38.2 (the total green area). The top green arrow is 38.2 (top blue) - 23.6 (top red) = 14.6. The bottom green area is 61.8 (bottom blue) - 38.2 (bottom red) = 23.6 (bottom green). Let's check the green ration: 14.6/38.2 = 38.2% and 23.6/38.2 = 61.8% (green arrows meet your golden ratio). Here's a golden ratio addict html/css version of your picture (I know your picture was for illustration purposes, but this was fun):

HTML

```
<div class="golden"></div>
<div class="dotted"></div>
<div class="blue top arrow"></div>
<div class="blue bottom arrow"></div>
<div class="red top arrow"></div>
<div class="red bottom arrow"></div>
<div class="green top arrow"></div>
<div class="green bottom arrow"></div>
```

CSS

```
html {
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}   

body {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 38.2%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 30.9%;
    position: relative;
}

.golden {
    position: absolute;
    top: 23.6%;
    bottom: 38.2%;
    width: 38.2%;
    background-color: #ddd;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -19.1%;
}

.dotted {
    position: absolute;
    top: 38.2%;
    height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px dotted #444;
}

.blue {
    position: absolute;
    right: 14.6%;
    width: 2px;
    background-color: #00f;
}

.blue.top {
    height: 38.2%;
    top: 0;
}

.blue.bottom {
    height: 61.8%;
    bottom: 0;
}

.red {
    position: absolute;
    right: 38.2%;
    width: 2px;
    background-color: #f00;
}

.red.top {
    height: 23.6%;
    top: 0;
}

.red.bottom {
    height: 38.2%;
    bottom: 0;
}

.green {
    position: absolute;
    right: 50%;
    width: 2px;
    background-color: #83f92c;
    border-color: #83f92c;
}

.green.top {
    height: 14.6%;
    top: 23.6%;
}

.green.bottom {
    height: 23.6%;
    bottom: 38.2%;
}

.arrow:before,
.arrow:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left: -6px;
    border-right:  7px solid transparent;
    border-left:   7px solid transparent;
}

.arrow:before {top: 0;}
.arrow:after {bottom: 0;}

.blue:before {border-bottom: 10px solid #00f;}
.red:before  {border-bottom: 10px solid #f00;}
.green:before {border-bottom: 10px solid #83f92c;}

.blue:after {border-top: 10px solid #00f;}
.red:after  {border-top: 10px solid #f00;}
.green:after {border-top: 10px solid #83f92c;}
```

EDIT 11-10-11: Based on the questioner's comment that my first interpretation above was not correct. I offer the fact that my solution will still work assuming the white area is the content container controlling the height (in case this is useful for anyone). In such a case, do this:

HTML

```
<div class="content">
    ...place some arbitrary length content here...
    [copy above HTML here]
</div>
```

CSS--first, remove `html` and `body` CSS from above. Then add:

```
.content {
    position: relative; 
   /* this is the only vital point, you can also style it 
      similar to the body css in the first version above, minus the height */
}
```

Comment: +1 thanks a lot Scott! I've learned a lot from your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've tested this and it appears to work.  The trick though requires the two `div`s, `inner` and `dummy` to have exactly the same contents.  `dummy` is used to give the `outer` div the appropriate height so that the `inner` div can be positioned by a percentage of that height.  A bit hacky but no javascript.

http://jsfiddle.net/fVQeC/4/

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        Something<br>too<br>more<br>more<br>more<br>more
    </div>
    <div class="dummy">
        Something<br>too<br>more<br>more<br>more<br>more
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
.outer{
    position: absolute;
    top: 38.2%;
}

.inner{
    width: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: -38.2%;
}

.dummy{
    width: 200px; 
   visibility: hidden; 
}
```