# Golden Ratio Webpage template?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a template webpage that uses the golden ratio for proportion. However, it appears I'm not doing it correctly.

I would like some advice on the proper use of:

1. `div` tags for laying out panels on a page
2. CSS and the position attribute
3. Any other tags or tips that will help me achieve an attractive page

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Golden Ratio</title>
    <link rel="StyleSheet" title="Default" href="gr.css" type="text/css">
</head> 
<body>          
    <div id="header">
    </div>  
    <div>
    </div>
    <div id="bodyleft">
    </div>      
    <div id="bodyright">
    </div>      
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: white;
}

#header {       
    width: 960px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}

#bodyleft {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px; 
    width: 592px;
    height: 700px;
    background-color: blue;
}

#bodyright {
    position: absolute;
    top: 110px;
    left: 610px;
    width: 368px;
    height: 700px;
    background-color: green;
}

#footer {
    position: absolute;     
    top: 800px;
    width: 960px;
    height: 100px;  
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: I like [this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/the-golden-ratio-in-web-design/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some rather extensive golden ratio work in this post [Is there a CSS way to position an HTML element vertically following the golden ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014775/is-there-a-css-way-to-position-an-html-element-vertically-following-the-golden-r/8015854#8015854) that may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

here is a link, http://jsfiddle.net/etienne_carre/WYStC/

I like to use the float left to align all my div and put a clear after it to finish the row.

Comment: And here is another link with a wrapper to center everything...http://jsfiddle.net/etienne_carre/WYStC/1/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help?
https://github.com/gbutiri/phi-grid

It's an extension that can be used with bootstrap and uses flexbox.